# JWT Refresh Tokens use

Tags: json, jwt

I’m currently building authentication for an app. When user signs up or signs in both refresh token and access token are set in cookies and on each request I check if access token is valid, if not then I refresh it if user has a valid refresh token. As I have read biggest complain about JWT’s is that if someone gets another user’s token, they can impersonate that user. In my understanding if a person can get other user’s access token then they probably can get their refresh token as easily and then still impersonate them. So my question is how does refresh token prevent this from happening? Maybe I am missing something.